# How to provide Gradle dependencies for Ant build

Tags: ant, groovy, gradle

I'm trying to migrate from ant to gradle. First phase of this is to move all dependecies to gradle.build and still build war via ant.

To import ant builds I'm using this code:

```
ant.importBuild('build.xml') { antTargetName ->
    'ant_' + antTargetName
}
```

To copy all dependencies from gradle to ant I'm trying to use this:

```
task copyDependenciesForAnt() {
    def antLibsPath = ant."tmp.build.dir" + "/" + ant."project.libs.folder"
    configurations.compile.each { Files.copy(Paths.get(it), Paths.get(antLibsPath)) }
}
ant_war.mustRunAfter copyDependenciesForAnt
```

With this code I have problem because i don't know how to use `Files.copy` here. Also there is probably easier way to achieve this in gradle, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a [`copy`](https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html) task in Gradle, as follows:

```
task copyDependenciesForAnt(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into ant."tmp.build.dir" + "/" + ant."project.libs.folder"
}

ant_war.dependsOn copyDependenciesForAnt
```

Also, I suggest using `dependsOn` rather than `mustRunAfter` for task dependency wiring which ensures correct execution order.